# static ip using systemd (debian 8) on RPI2

Tags: raspberry-pi, static-ip, systemd, debian-jessie

i'm new to systemd, very used to ubuntu\debian RC system scripts so i'm a bit confused.
the basic idea was to setup static ip for my raspberry pi ncluding dns etc...
naturally editing /etc/networking/interface does nothing as systemd-networkd is doing network configuration now.
But checking out /lib/systemd/network/ reveals:

```
pi@gal-pi:~ $ ls -l /lib/systemd/network/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 368 Jan 24 12:02 80-container-host0.network
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 378 Jan 24 12:02 80-container-ve.network
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  73 Jan 24 12:02 99-default.link
```

I have two interfaces on my pi eth0 which is connected and i want to set with static ipv4 and wlan0.
wlan0 doesn't get anything really and didn't bother to even try t set him up, eth0 however get's dhcp address.
Non of the scripts above seem to setup dhcp.

however:

```
pi@gal-pi:~ $ ls -l /etc/systemd/system/dhcpc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Mar 18 08:15 /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd5 -> /lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service
```

So there is a systemd dhcp service that is started on boot.bringing me to my questions:

1. should i setup dhcps service using dhcpcd.conf to setup static address on eth0 ?
2. should i use /etc/lib/systemd/network/40-eth0-static.network to setup the static address ?
3. how do i know who runs first dhcpd or networkd ? so they wont override each other ? i know systemd can be distributed in that it can run in parallel several services...
4. any other method i should use to setup static ip properly ?
5. if i'm at it do i need to use the same systemd-networkd scripts to setup wireless lan ? and if it's a hotspot (using hotap)

Comment: can't u just set up ur static ip on your router? that's what I did

Comment: linksys WRT-54G does not have dhcp mac address association. so no :-) i need to set it up. saw multiple answers here bu my no #3 is still a good question.

Answer (score 0):

`1.`: No idea whether you can set up static IP with dhcpcd or dhclient. Doesn't sound making sense though (I mean, why?).

`2.` You should have a `SOMENAME.network` file in `/etc/systemd/network`. SOMENAME doesn't have to be `40-eth0-static`. Although ordering the `.network` files with number prefix might be necessary under certain circumstances (but obviously not when you only have one).

`3.`: You should NOT run multiple network agents. This has nothing to do with `distributed` or `parallel several services` at all. They will conflict with each other since they essentially do the same thing. So use EITHER systemd-networkd OR dhcp"c"d (OR something else).

`4.`: It's up to you. You can use NetworkManager or so instead.

`5.`: AFAIK systemd-networkd cannot be used to set up Wi-Fi connection (e.g. connect to an SSID and authenticate to it). However, you can use it in companion with wpa_supplicant for IP address and so after the connection/authentication. This doesn't count as `multiple network agents`, since they do different stuff.

Comment: almost complete answer :-) the issue is, regarding your answer for #3, i didn't set up anything, rasberrian comes with dhcpd service running and networkd running, i get already dhcp for eth0 and 100% networkd is not responsible for it, so it's just dhcpd's doing, according to what you wrote i need to first disable dhcpd for eth0 before i add comfiguration, how do i do that ?

Comment: ok.
so from wandering around much data and raspberry pi forums it seems that:
1. systemd should still use /etc/network/interfaces
2. in that file it states i should use dhcpcd.conf
3. the reason is probably that in systemd there is a race between defaul dhcpccd service running and system which sets up the interfaces so setting it up in /etc/hdcpcd.conf solved the problem
4. the other approach would be to use hdcpcd@wlan0 target to still allow dhcpcd in the system and disable the main service  and set it static using systemd /etc/network